# What's the directory that Android studio gradle downloaded files into?

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

You know in China ,we can not interview google.com, so ,we can not download files such as gradle's about. Even if I can connect to google, the speed of the net is also so slow. So , anyone  who can help me to solve my problem? 
Look at the picture, every time I open the project, it download files every time! How can I stop it ? Or ,could you show me the directory of gradle download the files into ?I use windows system,window 7. Thank you for help!!

Comment: Emm, I can download the file with the Thunder Download Tool, so , now I want to know where to put it if I downloaded the files in other way?

Comment: Hmmm. But Google is not the only existing search engine. Here's a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines).

Answer (score 2):

Gradle download (by default) dependencies into its local ivy repository

```
C:\Users\<you>\.gradle\caches\
```

check `modules\files` directory

Comment: thanks ,but just put it into this folder or it's son folder? I see many of son folder in this directory .such as 2.2.1/2.8 etc.

Comment: @GojiSupport I am not sure how would you replicate that, those are hashed as well. Gradle manages them. But this is the answer to your question. Your best shot I think is to just put them into .m2 repo and add `mavenLocal()` to your repositories.

Comment: @GojiSupport by the way, the correct terminology is daughter folder, not son folder.